# ExtJS extended chart

Tags: extjs, charts, extend

ExtJS has Bar, Cartesian, Column, Line, Pie, Charts. They are very simple and generic based on Flash component http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2/build/charts/assets/charts.swf.

Is it other flash component availble and can be freely use with ExtJS ?

Is using other flash required special adaptation (extention) of Ext.chart.XXX class and when I can find more info (tutorial / manual) about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the flash based charting of ExtJS offers less features. You can go for [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) (which is not flash based). You need to use an [adapter](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?93669-Highcharts-adapter-and-plugin-for-ExtJS) for working with highcharts in ExtJS.

On the other hand, if you can wait,,... you can use the ExtJS 4 charting components which are not flash based but offer lots of features.

Comment: ExtJs 4 charts are out, and worlds better than in ExtJs 3.3, but I counter that HighCharts still has the edge. For example they have many more types and configuration properties, and every single one of the hundreds of properties has a working example on jsfiddle. That's why I'm sticking with Highcharts, even though my site is in Ext. See http://www.highcharts.com/ref/